# How to install mingw64-make command on ubuntu

Tags: xubuntu, make, mingw32

I need to build window version of startcoin on ubuntu and it contains installing `mingw64-make` command.
I already installed `make` and `mingw` on ubuntu but have difficulty in installing  `mingw64-make` command.
I have tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36770716/mingw64-make-build-error-bash-make-command-not-found, but there's no success.

I also tried https://www.tinc-vpn.org/examples/cross-compiling-64-bit-windows-binary/ but it does not contain `configure.ac` and it was not useful.

The final goal is to installing `mingw64-make` command, but have not found how to do that.

Any comment about `mingw64-make` will appreciate.

Comment: `mingw64-make` sounds like something you'd need to build **on** W64 - not **for** W64

Comment: But the documentation of the project say that run `mingw64-make` on ubuntu.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the documentation that you are following?